# data structure ,storing svg in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures

What is the best way to store svg path and all properties in array? I want to store in array and then map it to render. I dont need svg tag because I'm using styled component.

```
<svg width="8" height="11" viewBox="0 0 8 11">
            <path d="M1 4.04L4.04 1L7.08 4.04" stroke="#BACCD8" />
            <path d="M7.08008 6.46L4.04008 9.5L1.00008 6.46" stroke="#BACCD8" />
          </svg>

<svg width="8" height="7" viewBox="0 0 8 7">
            <path d="M1 4.04L4.04 1L7.08 4.04" stroke="#177FF2" />
            <path d="M4 4V7" stroke="#177FF2" />
          </svg>

<svg width="8" height="5" viewBox="0 0 8 5">
            <path d="M1 4.04L4.04 1L7.08 4.04" stroke="#177FF2" />
          </svg>
```

I need to make something like this:

```
const arrayOfSvg=[
  {
    path: `d="M1 4.04L4.04 1L7.08 4.04" stroke="#BACCD8"`,
    path: `d="M7.08008 6.46L4.04008 9.5L1.00008 6.46"`
  },
  {
    path: `d="M1 4.04L4.04 1L7.08 4.04" stroke="#177FF2"`,
    path: `d="M4 4V7" stroke="#177FF2"`
  },
  {
    path: `d="M1 4.04L4.04 1L7.08 4.04"` 
  }
]
```

But how should I add other properties like stroke, width, height for each svg  to make it more convenient for rendering using map ?

Comment: This question is not very clear at all.

Comment: I don't even understand how you'd `map` an array of objects to svgs, when one object in the array apparently has two `path` values. You cannot have two `path` keys in one object. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @TKoL with Object.values() , it returns an array

Comment: It doesn't return an array that contains both `path` values though, it only returns one.

Comment: @TKoL Object.keys

Comment: It only returns one. You cannot have two 'path' keys in one object. An object can only ever have one key with a particular name.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import img1 from "./yourpath/img1.svg";
import img2 from "./yourpath/img2.svg";
import img3 from "./yourpath/img3.svg";

const imgArray = [img1, img2, img3];

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="Home">
      <img src={imgArray[0]} alt="some alt" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Home />, rootElement);
```